# What kind of male plug is this for a 240V 20A machine?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, cord-and-plug

Need to wire a circuit for a machine that uses this type of plug. What type of receptacle and wire is needed?

[image: plug top down]

[image: plug side view]

I don't see a label on the plug.

Answer (score 4):

That is a NEMA **L6-20**. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NEMA_connector):

> L6-20 connectors provide a maximum of 20 amps and are commonly found in power distribution units (PDUs) used in the information technology sector. Most often, these connectors can be found in server rooms and data centers where the connectors are used to power equipment such as servers, backup systems and UPS units.

but I have found other references for this as a "welder" plug.

Except for the different connector, the wiring should be the same as for a NEMA 6-20:

- 2 hot wires, minimum 12 AWG
- 1 ground wire, minimum 12 AWG
- Double-pole 20A breaker (no smaller, no larger)
- If you use a /3 cable (black/white/red) then the hots are black and red and you cap the white wire.
- If you use a /2 cable (black/white) then the hots are black and white and you should mark both ends of the white wire with black or red tape, though in this situation (unlike a switch loop) the usage of white for hot should be obvious.

Comment: Thanks. This is for small industrial food processing equipment. I heard it uses a similar receptacle as welders so your finding makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

Will want a NEMA L6-20.  It is a locking type receptacle and will need 12 gauge wire.

Can use 12/2 cable but need a double breaker and use the white wire for the second hot/live.  Should tape/paint/mark the white wire with either black or red colour at both ends.

Connection is hot, hot, ground, with no neutral(white).

Comment: Thanks for the info. A tangent - how is there no neutral in the circuit? I get that each 20A breaker in the double-pole set provides 120V to each hot wire, supplying 240/250V. But don't those two hots need a neutral to complete the circuit? My understanding is ground wires are not meant to regularly complete the circuit as a neutral/return path, but it sounds like that's how it's happening in the setup you and @manassehkatz describe?

Comment: If you're using two-phase 240V, that's measured from one hot to the other hot; when one is high the other is low and vice versa. Neutral is taken from the middle of that transformer, so either hot is 120V relative to neutral. If your device only needs the 220, neutral goes unused and doesn't necessarily have to be present.

Comment: Another way to look at it: In a 120V circuit, current goes in on hot and out on neutral (or vice versa, flips 120 times per second). In a 240V circuit, current goes in on one hot and out *on the other hot* (and also flips 120 times per second). Where it gets really wacky is when you have combination (like a typical US clothes dryer or oven) that uses all three wires with some 120V (hot to neutral) and some 240V (hot to hot).